# Payroll breakdown by quarter sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table which looks like this

```
    EmployeeID | Name | Check Date | Check Num | Check Amount | Quarter
    1          | Test | 01/21/2018 | 001231312 | 500          | 1
    1          | Test | 03/01/2018 | 001233210 | 100          | 1
    1          | Test | 05/01/2018 | 123213321 | 13           | 2
    1          | Test | 08/01/2018 | 321909900 | 321          | 3
    1          | Test | 12/01/2018 | 321000132 | 123          |4
```

i need to display the following output

```
EmployeeID | Name | 1st Quarter Date | 1st Quarter Check Num | 1st Quarter Check Amount | 2nd Quarter Date | 2nd Quarter Check Num | 2nd Quarter Check Amount | 3rd Quarter Date | 3rd Quarter Check Num | 3rd Quarter Check Amount | 4th Quarter Date | 4th Quarter Check Num | 4th Quarter Check Amount
```

I was researching into this and I found information on using Pivot but it was unclear when it came to displaying details instead of some aggregate of the columns.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some samlpe data and expect result?

Comment: How did you decide `1st Quarter Date` `2nd Quarter Date` columns?

Comment: And more important, what check num would you expect to see by quarter?

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: You have two first quarter checks in your sample data.  Do you want to see both in the results or just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in my opinion would be to use Datepart(QUARTER, Check Date) combined with a case statement.

Example:

```
Select EmployeeID
   , Name
   , CASE WHEN Datepart(QUARTER, CheckDate) = 1 Then 'Check Date' END AS '1st Quarter Date'
   , CASE WHEN Datepart(QUARTER, CheckDate) = 1 Then 'Check Num' END AS '1st Quarter Check Num'
   , CASE WHEN Datepart(QUARTER, CheckDate) = 1 Then 'Check Amount' END AS '1st Quarter Check Amount'
   , CASE WHEN Datepart(QUARTER, CheckDate) = 2 Then 'Check Date' END AS '2nd Quarter Date'
   , CASE WHEN Datepart(QUARTER, CheckDate) = 2 Then 'Check Num' END AS '2nd Quarter Check Num'
   , CASE WHEN Datepart(QUARTER, CheckDate) = 2 Then 'Check Amount' END AS '2nd Quarter Check Amount' 
   , CASE WHEN Datepart(QUARTER, CheckDate) = 3 Then 'Check Date' END AS '3rd Quarter Date'
   , CASE WHEN Datepart(QUARTER, CheckDate) = 3 Then 'Check Num' END AS '3rd Quarter Check Num'
   , CASE WHEN Datepart(QUARTER, CheckDate) = 3 Then 'Check Amount' END AS '3rd Quarter Check Amount' 
   , CASE WHEN Datepart(QUARTER, CheckDate) = 4 Then 'Check Date' END AS '4th Quarter Date'
   , CASE WHEN Datepart(QUARTER, CheckDate) = 4 Then 'Check Num' END AS '4th Quarter Check Num'
   , CASE WHEN Datepart(QUARTER, CheckDate) = 4 Then 'Check Amount' END AS '4th Quarter Check Amount' 
From YourTableName
```

I am sure there are cleaner ways to do this and I'm sure others will chime in.
Also, please not I did not use the same Column names in Datepart, I believe you will need to '' due to the space (Datepart(QUARTER, 'Check Date').

EDIT: OP added some sample data and since there is a 'Quarter' Column, we can change the Case statement to:

```
CASE WHEN QUARTER = 1 Then ....
CASE WHEN QUARTER = 2 Then ....
CASE WHEN QUARTER = 3 Then ....
CASE WHEN QUARTER = 4 Then ....
```